# If file line starts with 001, convert last line to string JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, list

I already have a part of my project that adds adds all lines that start with 111 to a list. But im struggling to find any information anywhere on how to only output the last line that starts with 111.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(searchObject + ".txt"))) {
    List<String> abc = stream.filter(str->str.startsWith("111"))
            .map(s->s.split("111")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(abc);    // A C Z
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Example:

1. 001 A
2. 111 C
3. 222 B
4. 111 F
5. 202 L

I am trying to get an output of "F" only.

Im using Java 8 on Eclipse. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting something entirely new, this could be done by keeping the above code, and deleting everything in the list but the last item. This is what worked

String last = abc.get(abc.size() - 1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `reduce` step in the stream to just retain the last value:

```java
Optional<String> result = stream.filter(str->str.startsWith("111"))
    .map(s->s.split("\\s+")[1])
    .reduce((accum, entry) -> entry);
```

`reduce` is normally used to accumulate values, but here it is just using the last value.

The result is an `Optional<String>` because the filter might result in no matches.

I have used `"\\s+"` as the pattern for the `split` to split on spaces so that the result only contains `F` with no leading space.